# Revealing the whole binary in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binary

I would like to know how is it possible for jquery to show the whole binary of a number and not take away the leading zeros.

Take a look at the code:

In HTML:

```
<input id="input" type="text" size="20">
<input id="result" type="text" size="30">
<input id="submit" type="button">
```

In jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var x = $("#input").val(); 
        var array = x.split(".");
        $("#result").val((array[0]*1).toString(2) + " " + (array[1]*1).toString(2) + " " + (array[2]*1).toString(2) + " " + (array[3]*1).toString(2));  

    });

});
```

When, for example, i use the number 128 the result is 100000000 (correct), but when i use the number 1 the result will be 1 instead of 00000001 or for 32 it will be 100000 instead of 00100000, it doesn't show the leading zeros.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Noshiz/D5hfh/) to experiment with it yourself.

Any ideas how to apear the leading zeros?

Also would be possible to apply the `.toString()` in the whole array at once, without having to add it manually to each array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` is as correct as `00000001`, none of them is "whole". If you prefer the latter, you should complement by adding as many zeros as you want.

To complement to a length of `8`, for example, you may do this :

```
var s = yourNumber.toString(2);
var completed = "00000000".slice(s.length) + s;
```

EDIT :

for the new question you just added, if you want to apply this transformation to all parts of a splitted string, do

```
var completedNumbers = $("#input").val().split(".").map(Number).map(function(v){
     var s = v.toString(2);
     return "00000000".slice(s.length)+s
});
var joinedCompletedNumbers = completedNumbers.join(' ');
```

Comment: For some reason the first code did not work as expected, because it wasn't translating the number into binary, but the second one works perfectly, it was exactly what i was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @Nick The first code was meant to be clearer to other users, you had to use `x` instead of `yourNumber`. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes, ofc i changed the yourNumber to x, but it didnt work. And just out of curiocity i just tryed again, but it doesn't translate any number into binary. The second one works like a charm, one note thought, at the end instead of declaring one more variable you can add the .join(' ') in the end of the .map(function(v){}).join(' ');
But i guess you did that just to be more clear for someone to read and understand whats going on. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nick I get the problem you had : yourNumber must be a number, not just a string holding a number (that is `"2"` isn't ok while `2` is). That parsing step is done in the second code with `map(Number)`.

Comment: *sigh* yes you are right, i forgot that it was a string.. I tested it again and now it works perfectly. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to fix how many leading zero you want to show. Supoose you want to show 8 digit. Then....

```
function pad (str, max) {
      str = str.toString();
      return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
    }
```

And use it like

```
 your_result=pad(your_result, 8);
```

This will give 00000001 if you got result 1.

Comment: Your code worked the best for me, but it didn't translate the number into binary, but i found a workaround with this var test = pad((array[0]*1).toString(2), 8);

Thanks for your help.